# How can I flip object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been working on boat race game and I have a problem with rotate to boat object. My boat object has rigidbody, mesh collider, mesh renderer and mesh filter components. When I try to rotate boat in Update function  boat rotates clearly 90 degrees but there is a problem that after 90 degrees it seems like 2 boat object one of them is not rotated one of them is continue rotating.

```
if (!GameManager.instance.isRotate) 
{
   rotationX = 0;
   rb.AddTorque(0f,h*turnSpeed*Time.deltaTime,0f);

   rb.AddForce(-transform.forward*accelerate);
}
else
{
   rotationX += speed * Time.deltaTime;

   transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, 
   transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.z);
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe add a video or a gif of what you're seeing in the editor?

Comment: When I use addTorque instead of localrotation, everything works fine. I think there is a problem with usage of localrotation in Update function. I solved my problem but still thanks a lot for answer

Comment: Suggestions: game is all about looping things. so your this code must be in a loop. which tell its continuously rotating  and for another which is not rotating its about clearing object. I AM JUST TELLING CHECK THAT you must double check. lastly if you are adding something like ( AddForce ) you must delete it as well.

Comment: Great that you've solved it! Rotation in Unity is tricky since it's based on Quaternions and doesn't really work too great when you try to work with Euler angles. So try to stay away from those when you have to rotate an object this much.